# Number of comments on shares impossibly greater than zero

Tags: facebook

After clicking on the "reach" number on a Facebook post, as an admin of a Facebook post, I get these numbers:

[image: 873 people reached, 65 likes, comments & shares, 9 likes (8 on post, 1 on shares), 56 comments (32 on post, 24 on shares), 0 shares (0 on post, 0 on shares)]

As you can see from this screenshot, this post supposedly has received 24 comments on shares. However, it also says that it has zero shares! How can this be?